# Laravel: Get multiple records from database with innerjoin

Tags: database, laravel

I'm trying to fetch data from the database using some innerjoins. However, there is a table that respond to the same identifier (not primary id).

Is there a way to get more then one record?

[image: db]
The table I'm trying to get multiple records from is "pokemon_types".

```php
            $kanto = DB::table('starter')
                ->join('pokemon_species', 'pokemon_species.pokemon_id', '=', 'starter.pokemon_id')
                ->join('pokemon_species_names', 'pokemon_species_names.pokemon_species_id', '=', 'pokemon_species.pokemon_id')
                ->join('pokemon_types', 'pokemon_types.pokemon_id', '=', 'starter.pokemon_id')
                ->where('pokemon_species_names.local_language_id', '=', '9')
                ->where('starter.region', '=', 'kanto')
                ->get();
```

Right now the code returns 2 records instead of the desired 1.

[image: dump]

Comment: It doesn't appear you are actually using anything from that `pokemon_types` table so it doesn't seem like it's necessary to join that.  Can you just remove the join?  Otherwise it might be better just to use laravel relations for this since that won't cause duplication like this.

Comment: Well, I want to use type_id and slot. So I need to call that table.

Comment: The results returned by the query has different values for type_id and slot so if you need to use them, you need this duplication to occur to sort those out so this doesn't really seem like an issue now.  Is it possible these results are correct, you just want them to be grouped by the species for now?

Comment: Yes, if I can group the type_id field that would solve my problem. Been Googling for a while now and I don't know if that's possible?

Comment: Anyone maybe? I just need to create an array of some sorts and so when I loop the data I can display both types.

Comment: Are you committed to using inner joins or would you be open to using the model relations as described in the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).  I'd be happy to walk you through it and I really feel like the model relations would be the better route since it will put everything into arrays in a more natural manner to your app.